# Swap slot Task in AzureDevops for FunctionApp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops

I have a App service and a Function App created in my Azure Portal.

Using Azure Devops pipeline Task i am willing to do swap slot.

I found above link. Is this same link applicable to do swap for FunctionApp as well? Not clear from documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed a function app is hosted in an app service. This is why you should use the same azure devops task in order to swap slots. You can locate your app service plan using the slots window

[image]